# running an oozie workflow using java code

Tags: java, hadoop, workflow, oozie

I'm new to java and having some trouble running an oozie job using java code. I am unable to figure out the problem in the code. Some help will be really appreciated. Here's my code

```
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient;
import org.apache.oozie.client.WorkflowJob;

public class oozie {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    OozieClient wc = new OozieClient("http://host:11000/oozie");

    Properties conf = wc.createConfiguration();

    conf.setProperty(OozieClient.APP_PATH, "hdfs://cluster/user/apps/merge-psp-logs/merge-wf/workflow.xml");
    conf.setProperty("jobTracker", "jobtracker.bigdata.com:8021");
    conf.setProperty("nameNode", "hdfs://namenode.bigdata.com:8020");
    conf.setProperty("queueName", "jobtracker.bigdata.com:8021");
    conf.setProperty("appsRoot", "hdfs://namenode.bigdata.com:8020/user/workspace/apps");
    conf.setProperty("appLibLoc", "hdfs://namenode.bigdata.com:8020/user/workspace/lib");
    conf.setProperty("rawlogsLoc", "hdfs://namenode.bigdata.com:8020/user/workspace/");
    conf.setProperty("mergedlogsLoc", "jobtracker.bigdata.com:8021");
    try {
        String jobId = wc.run(conf);
        System.out.println("Workflow job submitted");

        while (wc.getJobInfo(jobId).getStatus() == WorkflowJob.Status.RUNNING) {
            System.out.println("Workflow job running ...");
            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
        }
        System.out.println("Workflow job completed ...");
        System.out.println(wc.getJobInfo(jobId));
    } catch (Exception r) {
        System.out.println("Errors");
    }
}
}
```

Though i am able to launch the job using command line

Comment: Compilation or runtime error?

Comment: @GiulioQuaresima gives me runtime errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any further information, i would say this is the probably cause of your runtime errors:

```
conf.setProperty(OozieClient.APP_PATH, 
    "hdfs://cluster/user/apps/merge-psp-logs/merge-wf/workflow.xml");
conf.setProperty("jobTracker", "jobtracker.bigdata.com:8021");
conf.setProperty("nameNode", "hdfs://namenode.bigdata.com:8020");
conf.setProperty("queueName", "jobtracker.bigdata.com:8021");
```

Unless you have two clusters, my guess is you meant the APP_PATH to point to the same HDFS instance as the one named in your nameNode property, in which case try:

```
conf.setProperty(OozieClient.APP_PATH, 
    "hdfs://namenode.bigdata.com:8020/user/apps/merge-psp-logs/merge-wf/workflow.xml");
```

You might also want to change the queueName to a real queue name (probably "default", unless `jobtracker.bigdata.com:8021` is the actual name of your queue):

```
conf.setProperty("queueName", "default");
```

Aside from those observations, try and post the actual runtime error you're seeing.

Comment: made the required changes. don't have anymore runtime errors. the console prints "Errors" as per the exception defined. any idea what might be the reason?

Comment: Seriously, this would be a lot easier if you posted the errors you're seeing

Comment: got the thing working. it was because of, firstly the changes which you asked to make and lastly, including json-simple jar in the classpath